No TabsContext provided when creating tab with hooksAPI in mui/base
I am new to Material UI Base. I am trying to create a tab component with hooksAPI from Material Base UI. But i am getting error No TabsContext provided
Used useTabs, useTabsList, useTab hooks from BaseUI from Material UI.
Attaching the screenshot of the error and codesandbox link to reproduce it.
Screenshot Attached: 
Here is the link of Codesandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/thirsty-benji-wvz5dq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
any help would be appreciated
